# how to perform NTLM authentication from browser in windows domain?

Tags: php, c++, security, active-directory, ntlm

I have to check user credentials against windows domain controller. User credentials are given in web GUI, and it would be nice not to pass raw password from client to server. On server side I have PHP and C++, I can use WinAPI. 
Does anybody have ideas how to pass user login/password safely (for call to LogonUser), or other ways to perform authentication, probably using NTLM or DIGEST ?
Also, I need list of groups (local and global, including indirect) in which logged on user has membership.

Modifying existing PHP extension is also an option.